# Volume : Square base towards circle top

Tags: modeling, bevel

Did you know how to model this bevel ? I need to reproduce them but i can't.

Best regards,
A Frenchman in shit

[image: Side view of object]

[image: top view]

Comment: Are you asking how to model a tapered bevel? So a sharp square at the base and a rounded bevel at the top?

Comment: Yes, Exactly ! I don't know how to do it.